# CTRL + P prints doesn't print more than 1 page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, printing

I have an HTML page that puts several images dynamically created using JPGraph in the following way:

```
 <div class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
        <nav class="demo-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-color--blue-grey-800">
            <form  id ="target">
                Start Date:
                    <input type ="date" name ="startDate" value="2012-01-04"/>
                 <p> </p>
                 End Date: &nbsp
                    <input type ="date" name ="endDate" value= <?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?> >
                <br>
                <br>
                Report Type
                <br>
                    &nbsp<input type="checkbox" name = "session" value="session"> Longest Sessions
                <br>
                    &nbsp<input type="checkbox" name = "export" value="export"> Export Data
                <br>
                    &nbsp<input type="checkbox" name = "format" value="format"> Format Data
                <br>
                    &nbsp<input type="checkbox" name = "scan" value="scan"> Scan Data
                <br>
                <br>
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
                <input type="button" value = "Print" onclick="window.print();return false;"/>
            </form>
<script>
                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    $("#target").submit(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var form_data = new FormData(this);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "DrawGraphs.php", // Url to which the request is send
                            type: "post",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                            data: form_data, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                            processData: false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                            {
                                document.getElementById("graphs").innerHTML = "";
                                console.log( 'ready!' );
                                //var myImages = '';
                                for(var image in data) {
                                    $("#graphs").append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data[image]+ '"/>'+);
                                     //myImages += '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data[image]+ '"/>';

                                };
                                //$("#graphs").html(myImages);
                            },error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                                console.log(errorThrown );
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

            </script>

<main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
    <div class = "mdl-js-layout">
        <div id = "graphs" class="mdl-grid demo-content">
         <p>Select the types of report and the date range to search.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</div>
```

The problem arises when I try to print out the page either using JavaScript window.print function and CTRL + P. It seems that it doesn't print out more than a single page and it will only print the current frame the scroll bar is on up to the end of that page. I've found that I may need to add a @media print in my css file, but that seemed to have no effect on the printing. I added the following into the css file:

```
@media print {
    body{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

I don't really understand how to define how and what to print within css, so if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have scrollbars on the div inside the page? but printing the parent page so it only prints whatever is visible in viewport. What do you see in print preview?

Comment: I don't have any scroll bars explicitly defined anywhere from what I could tell. I looked deeper into the mdl classes that I am using and by adding an additional div element from mdl, I was able to print out the whole page. It just shrinks all the content to fit on a single page. However it's still not what I want and I would like to understand why this is happening to begin with.

Comment: As for the parent page, I don't really have a parent page as all the content is updated on a single page. Print preview still shows a single page and it also shows the date printed and the url which is partially covered by the image.